# Schema of unstructured data can be defined at query time

Tags: nosql

I am looking for an example to understand the following statement:

Schema of unstructured data can be defined at query time

Answer (score 0):

The statement "*Schema of unstructured data can be defined at query time*" sounds like a little bit of poor choice of words but likely eludes to the point that *all* data has a structure, even if it hasn't been defined explicitly yet (such as in a relational database management system).

In the context of **NoSQL**, an unstructured dataset such as **JSON** may not explicitly define things like the data types of the data itself, but the consuming applications of that data may define the **schema** of that data **explicitly** ahead of time such as when defining models to *physically* represent your data as objects.

For example, TypeScript is a JavaScript framework where you can define class files to store your model definitions that deserialize the **JSON** data into objects, such as when you receive data back from a restful web service. Furthermore, you can then persist that data into another database system, such as SQLite for example, where the **schema** is materialized with different (but compatible) data types. TypeScript has the [`number`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) data type whereas you could store the same data in SQLite as [`INTEGER` or `REAL`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) depending on what fits your use case.

The point being, there is no defined **schema** at the source of the data, but once it's queried and consumed in an application, it is possible to define one, or even multiple **schemas** that appropriately fit the shape of the data.

Additionally, some applications **implicitly** define a **schema** around the data they consume, for example, with an [**ORM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping), or with data migration tools. The purpose of an **ORM** is to literally define concrete models for a particular set of data. While most **ORMs** usually consume structured data, there are unstructured **ORMs** as well.